# how to make a shell execute with suid

Tags: bash, shell, unix-shell, ksh, suid

I'm trying to suid a shell and it's not working.  I need help understanding why, and how to fix it...

I'm following these steps (as root)

```
cp /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bash-emergency
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/bash-emergency
```

bash-emergency is owned by root:root

I would expect that this should execute bash-emergency as root, resulting in a root shell

I know all the reasons not to do this.  This is in a lab.  su and sudo, for the sake of this test, are not an option.  I need a user to be able to get a root shell without having to authenticate or otherwise be challenged after their initial login.

I'm hoping to be able to do this with a simple suid executable rather than changing the non-root user's UID to 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong other that breaking all security measures on the system and possibly on the network. When you execute your suid binary, what is the output of the `id` command?

Comment: what are you trying to solve? looks for me like a homework

Comment: @doneal24 the output is 'uid=1000(ec2-user) gid=1000(ec2-user) euid=0(root) groups=1000(ec2-user),4(adm),10(wheel),190(systemd-journal)'  Notice the EUID is 0, but the UID is still my rergular UID.  In this condition, some commands run as root (ie. touch x), but programs that actually check for root give the message "You must be root to run this command."

Comment: @djdomi Definitely not homework.   I am setting up a Unix class environment where the students will have direct access to root -- including the ability to render su and sudo useless.  I won't really have a way to get to the console, boot into single-user mode, and fix them.  My goal here is, hoping the students haven't also broken ssh, that I can pop in and use an "emergency shell" to fix the damage they did... ie broken pam, broken sudoers, etc.  This happened the last time I taught the class... just trying to find a way to fix it if it happens again.

Comment: The behavior seems consistent with bash and ksh, so I don't think it's shell-specific.

Comment: Just a bump -- anyone have any ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is running face-first into a security measure designed to keep the system safe. Bash, dash, and other shells detect that they're being run setuid root and immediately drop privileges on launch. This is because setting them suid root is a very common privilege escalation tactic.

Fortunately, there's a really easy work around for you. Launch your suid shell as `/usr/bin/bash-emergency -p`.

Relevant quote from the docs:

> If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the -p option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the SHELLOPTS, BASHOPTS, CDPATH, and GLOBIGNORE variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.   Unfortunately, the behavior is the same with or without the -p with respect to privilege.  I can touch a file and it will be owned by root, as expected, but if an application specifically tests if the user running it is root, it still fails because the UID doesn't get set to zero.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/bash-emergency` owned by root? Nevermind, answered in the original post.

Comment: Yes, you have root privileges, and can do root things, but you'll still be your previous user. You can still fix /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/sudoers, /root/.ssh and so forth. If you need full root shell for something, it's best to bootstrap yourself back to a proper root shell using one of those. I can drop another answer on how to compile a binary that will do it in a single step if you like.

Comment: That would be interesting to see.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While shell programs deliberately don't do what you want, you could create your own program that does. This is an example program that will check if you have euid root, and if so, run a specific command as uid root.

Usage is something like `/usr/bin/emergency-backdoor /usr/bin/bash`, or `/usr/bin/emergency-backdoor "/usr/bin/vim /etc/passwd"`, and so forth.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc != 2) { 
        puts("Usage: <this> \"command and args\"");
        return 1;
    } else if (geteuid() == 0) { 
        setuid(0);
        setgid(0);
        puts("Executing the following as root");
        puts(argv[1]);
        system(argv[1]);
    } else {
        puts("You do not have privs");
    }
    return 0;
}
```